# Meteor React Notification Component

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have the following code which works on JQuery.

```
 (function($) {

    'use strict';

    var Notification = function(container, options) {

        var self = this;

        // Element collection
        self.container = $(container); // 'body' recommended
        self.notification = $('<div class="pgn"></div>');
        self.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.pgNotification.defaults, options);

        if (!self.container.find('.pgn-wrapper[data-position=' + this.options.position + ']').length) {
            self.wrapper = $('<div class="pgn-wrapper" data-position="' + this.options.position + '"></div>');
            self.container.append(self.wrapper);
        } else {
            self.wrapper = $('.pgn-wrapper[data-position=' + this.options.position + ']');
        }

        self.alert = $('<div class="alert"></div>');
        self.alert.addClass('alert-' + self.options.type);

        if (self.options.style == 'bar') {
            new BarNotification();
        } else if (self.options.style == 'flip') {
            new FlipNotification();
        } else if (self.options.style == 'circle') {
            new CircleNotification();
        } else if (self.options.style == 'simple') {
            new SimpleNotification();
        } else { // default = 'simple'
            new SimpleNotification();
        }

        // Notification styles
        function SimpleNotification() {

            self.notification.addClass('pgn-simple');

            self.alert.append(self.options.message);
            if (self.options.showClose) {
                var close = $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>')
                    .append('<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>')
                    .append('<span class="sr-only">Close</span>');

                self.alert.prepend(close);
            }

        }

        function BarNotification() {

            self.notification.addClass('pgn-bar');

            self.alert.append('<span>' + self.options.message + '</span>');
            self.alert.addClass('alert-' + self.options.type);


            if (self.options.showClose) {
                var close = $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>')
                    .append('<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>')
                    .append('<span class="sr-only">Close</span>');

                self.alert.prepend(close);
            }

        }

        function CircleNotification() {

            self.notification.addClass('pgn-circle');

            var table = '<div>';
            if (self.options.thumbnail) {
                table += '<div class="pgn-thumbnail"><div>' + self.options.thumbnail + '</div></div>';
            }

            table += '<div class="pgn-message"><div>';

            if (self.options.title) {
                table += '<p class="bold">' + self.options.title + '</p>';
            }
            table += '<p>' + self.options.message + '</p></div></div>';
            table += '</div>';

            if (self.options.showClose) {
                table += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">';
                table += '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>';
                table += '</button>';
            }


            self.alert.append(table);
            self.alert.after('<div class="clearfix"></div>');

        }

        function FlipNotification() {

            self.notification.addClass('pgn-flip');
            self.alert.append("<span>" + self.options.message + "</span>");
            if (self.options.showClose) {
                var close = $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>')
                    .append('<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>')
                    .append('<span class="sr-only">Close</span>');

                self.alert.prepend(close);
            }

        }

        self.notification.append(self.alert);

        // bind to Bootstrap closed event for alerts 
        self.alert.on('closed.bs.alert', function() {
            self.notification.remove();
            self.options.onClosed();
            // refresh layout after removal
        });

        return this; // enable chaining
    };

    Notification.VERSION = "1.0.0";

    Notification.prototype.show = function() {

        // TODO: add fadeOut animation on show as option
        this.wrapper.prepend(this.notification);

        this.options.onShown();

        if (this.options.timeout != 0) {
            var _this = this;
            // settimeout removes scope. use .bind(this)
            setTimeout(function() {
                this.notification.fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                    _this.options.onClosed();
                });
            }.bind(this), this.options.timeout);
        }

    };

    $.fn.pgNotification = function(options) {
        return new Notification(this, options);
    };

    $.fn.pgNotification.defaults = {
        style: 'simple',
        message: null,
        position: 'top-right',
        type: 'info',
        showClose: true,
        timeout: 4000,
        onShown: function() {},
        onClosed: function() {}
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

My main concern is. Since this modifies the DOM, by practice that negates the use of REACT in a way. How best can I implement this as a component or this is not something to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

The "[React way](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)" is to put as much functionality in the state of your component and then link your UI to that state to automatically handle your changes. Without going line by line through your code and proposing a solution (which isn't the point of this site), it's difficult to provide a simple answer. But the basic idea would be as follows:

- Get the notification data via props to the component
- Store attributes of the notification in the state (like open/closed, etc)
- Write functions to modify the state which are triggered by UI events

I have a non-meteor notifications component that gets the data via API, and then a websocket to listen to changes to add to the list. Functions directly modify the state of the notifications (like read/unread) so that the UI is automatically updated.

React also has a [whole transitions module](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) you can incorporate once you have the basic component working.